# prevent direct linking to files from other domains with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns

I want to prevent other websites from direct linking the files available for download on my server. Instead, i want to redirect the visitors to a php file where i will display ads before the user can download the files.

So if someone try to access `www.example.com/file.exe` then i want to redirect the user to `www.example.net/somescript.php?download=file.exe`

However, the users must still be able to access `file.exe` if he is coming from `www.example.com`. But if he is coming from a different domain then i want to redirect him to `somescript.php?download=XXXXX`

This way, `file.exe` would only be accessible from my own domain and incoming traffic from external websites would be forced to go through somescript.php where i would display ads before the users can leech files.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com(/)?.*$     [NC]
 RewriteRule ([^/]+\.[a-z0-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/somescript.php?download=$1 [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: actually file.exe should be a variable, so if i go to www.example.com/anotherfile.exe then it would redirect to somescript.php?download=anotherfile.exe

Comment: And what if the extension is different from .exe ? It can also be zip, rar, tar, gz, 7z, etc... Sorry forgot to mention that.